# loop is not showing Zero before numbers in framework

Tags: php, mysql, string, frameworks

I am making a form in custom framework in which when user enter 2 numbers  e.g start number and ending number . the loop shows all numbers between those numbers . for example if user enter 0300 and 0309 
the result will show

> 0300
>
> 0301
>
> 0302
>
> 0303
>
> 0304
>
> 0305
>
> 0306
>
> 0307
>
> 0308
>
> 0309

but it is showing

> 0300
>
> 301
>
> 302
>
> 303
>
> 304
>
> 305
>
> 306
>
> 307
>
> 308
>
> 309

Is there a problem with my loop ?

```
function did_ehmad_sec_submit($editForm) {
$count=0;
$start=$editForm['from_to'];
$end=$editForm['to_range'];
$desc=$editForm['description'];

for ($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i++)
{
$result = mysql_query("INSERT into did_number(did_number, description) VALUES ('$i','$desc')");
}

return $result; 
}
```

Comment: i am using return instead of echo

Comment: There's no leading 0 in base10 numbers, you could cast to string with a padding 0

Comment: so what should i do now

Answer (score 0):

**Courtesy** : [In PHP, how do I add to a zero-padded numeric string and preserve the zero padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718229/1288198)

try using this..

```
sprintf('%04d', $num);
```

Comment: where? please elaborate

Comment: Replace `echo 0301` with `sprintf('%04d', 0301);`

Comment: well should i use $result instead of 0301 ?

Comment: yeah. you got it right.

Comment: still the same ! Only first result shows 0 .
0300

301

302

303

304

305

306

307

308

309
like this

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you've not tagged your question as being MySQL, this is clearly what's in use.

As such, if you want to store the numbers in the database with a set number of digits (including preceding zeros), one solution would be to make use of the `ZEROFILL` attribute. (See the MySQL [Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) manual page  for more information.)

Answer (score 0):

0 is removed automatically. So you can append manually or use  ZEROFILL for a numeric column

Comment: In database while creating table. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html like **data_type: [ZEROFILL] **